# gradle.build issue - 15.0.0 15.0.1 conflict with ads-identifier

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

When loading `com.google.android.gms:play-services-*` packages same version needs to be used in different packages.

I'm importing `gms-location` and `gms-analytics` using:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.0'
```

I'm Using version `15.0.0` in both since `location` latest version is `15.0.1` yet analytics is skipping `15.0.1`, latest is `15.0.2`.

So `15.0.0` is the latest common release.

Versions list can be seen here:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Im getting an error about `com.google.android.gms:ads-identifier` (which imports itself somehow) it's version is 15.0.1 - the conflict creates runtime issues in release versions.

How do I get rid of `ads-identifier` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the release [notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases), just like firebase, play services libs now have independent versions as well. So add them with their respective versions:

> Google Play services libraries after 15.0.0 now have independent
>   version numbers

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2'
```

Check as well if your gms plugin is up to date:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
```

Comment: Android studio gives an error about using different version, checking for android studio update

Comment: check as well if your gms plugin is up to date